# Testing Rails application with plenty of seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, fixtures

I'm maintaining a Rails 3.1 app. App db has more than 50+ tables and maybe 30 of those need seed data for the app to function correctly.

App has plenty of statistical data (as a seed data) and some tables contain more than 150 000 records. I have been testing using fixtures (actually using rake tasks to create fixture files from dev-db). Because of huge fixture files, testing has become slower and slower. We're talking about 20+ minutes to run the whole test suite.

At the time I started making tests, fixtures were way to go. Currently I'm not so sure anymore. I keep reading about tools like factory_girl, capybara, rspec and spork. I've done few tests with those and they seem nice and fun to use.

*Basically I'd like to know how would you test this kind of setup?*

Fixtures are way too slow. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, with application as huge as yours, the test suite should be running very long also. I think the greatest improvement here would be using less testing data in the database.
 You can test associations or whatever it is you're doing db-related, but when you're testing model functionality for example, set up mock expectations on `#save` method and verify that your code changed `@attributes` of the model. I think that testing everything against the database is redundant. You don't have to include rails stack as your testing target (which you do when you save to the database), as it's very thoroughly tested already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm thinking of removing fixtures completely and testing agains seed-data-only db. Besides I'd like to use database_cleaner gem to cleanup certain tables (not seed data ones) to have a fresh start for each test. Ideas for this approach?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't recommend you any approaches on database cleaning in testing environment. None of my tests use database and I don't know such strategies.